# Error "Cannot read property 'color' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried `nachos-ui` in the first time with `Button` and `Input` however same error occurs

`TypeError "Cannot read property 'color' of undefined"`

Some thing wrong with me?

```
"react-native": 0.58.5
"nachos-ui": "^0.2.0-beta.1"
```

node version `v10.15.1`

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Bubble } from 'nachos-ui';


class AddPost extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Button> 
            Button
        </Button>
        <Bubble>
            Hello, How Are you ?
        </Bubble>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AddPost;
```

Comment: please provide some code …

Comment: is just like that :
<Button > 
            Button </Button>

Comment: @Soufianeelamrani Please add the full code in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @Tanveerbyn i added it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your app in a theme provider for `nachos-ui` components to render.

See: https://github.com/nachos-ui/nachos-ui

From the docs:

```
The ThemeProvider component should be set at the highest level of your app. If it is not, Nachos UI components will NOT render.

import { ThemeProvider } from "nachos-ui";

export default (App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider>
    <RestOfYourApp />
  </ThemeProvider>
));
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Button } from 'nachos-ui'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
        <Button>Button</Button>
    </View>
  )
}
```

To just make it work in your case, try this (note that the ThemeProvider should really be located at the top-level of your app, generally `App.js`):

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {Button,Bubble,ThemeProvider} from 'nachos-ui';


class AddPost extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <View>
          <Button > 
              Button
          </Button>
          <Bubble>
              Hello, How Are you ?
          </Bubble>
        </View>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default AddPost;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: should i create a new component and write the code between <ThemeProvider>  </ThemeProvider> and after all that call this component or what exactly ?

Comment: Try wrapping your components in a `<ThemeProvider>`. Updated my answer above